# how do I subtotal Calculated measure by Year Date dimension in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to subtotal my years.  When I do so the subtotal is a crazy #.

```
test = [MT]/[FA]

Formula for Cells = ((SUM([test]))*12)*(SUM([FA]) / TOTAL(SUM([FA])))
```

Formula is calculating using pane down[image]

Comment: can you share public link of workbook with sample data you have ?

Comment: https://public.tableau.com/views/SubtotalCalculatedMeasure/Sheet1?:embed=y&:display_count=yes&:showTabs=y           -  I made one with fake sample data here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `test` calculation as :

```
SUM( [MT] )/SUM( [Faccounts] )
```

Your window calculation will error out.

Materialise your `main calculation` as below :

```
(([test])*12)*(SUM([Faccounts]) / TOTAL(SUM([Faccounts])))
```

You will get correct result .
Somehow I am unable to upload the workbook .

Comment: this does not help.  In fact it makes all the individual numbers wrong as well as the totals.

Comment: I validated the results side by side . Did you use `using pane down`